# Why don't we all eat injera? Or some other form(s) of teff?

Tags: bread, flavor, nutrient-composition, tasting

We are supposed to eat high-protein foods, yet even people without celiac disease complain about gluten...

Tuff, unlike quinoa, is a true cereal grass, and like quinoa, is high in protein that is not gluten... Right?

So why isn't the whole world gorging on injera, or some other form of teff?

Comment: I'm sure there's some form of specific agricultural history question about where a grain has been grown that'd be answerable, but I'm not sure exactly what it'd be or whether it'd be on topic here. In the current form, though, you're just asking why people don't pick their diet the way you think they should/would, and that's definitely both off-topic and likely to solicit opinions.

Comment: One key sentence in the Wikipedia article on teff: "it does not tolerate frost." That means it's unlikely to be viable as a crop in many of the parts of the world that currently produce wheat.

Comment: the majority of people don't complain about gluten and happily consume the grain that is traditional in their own region.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because there is a shortage of teff. You might want to look at this article from January, 2021, but it does not provide all the answers.

I personally love injera, but I have not been buying teff for a few years after hearing of this problem. Similar problems may be going in with quinoa, but I have not yet researched that.

I generally stick to things such as wild rice. Of I know where and how it is grown, but that's quite expensive. I try to put my money and my mouth where it makes a difference.

[What Are the Domestic and Regional Impacts From Ethiopia's Policy on the Export Ban of Teff?](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fsufs.2020.00004/full)

Comment: I don't know any export bans on quinoa, but it's possible that it was done because of what happened with that grain many years ago.  When quinoa started getting popular, there were reports that the prices shot up so quickly that farmers were selling it for export, leaving little available in the local villages and the non-farmers not being able to afford what little there was available.  I assume they've managed to compensate (or politicians don't care), as there were also reports that Peru signed an agreement with China to allow exports.